# No artists with labels found to put in legend

Tags: pandas, for-loop, matplotlib

I am using for loop to plot pandas dataframe using pyplot. The problem I have is that when I try to add a legend to the plot it shows the following message: "No artists with labels found to put in legend.  Note that artists whose label start with an underscore are ignored when legend() is called with no argument."

This is the code I am using:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(8,4))

plt.title("Solvent Performance")

plt.grid()

for column in file:
    if column != 'G/L ratio':
        plt.plot(file['G/L ratio'], file[column])
        plt.scatter(file['G/L ratio'], file[column])
    
plt.xlabel('ratio')
plt.ylabel('removal efficiency (%)')

plt.legend()

plt.show()

plt.savefig('dummy.jpeg', dpi=300)
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Add the data sample as text, not as a picture. E.g. try `file.to_dict()` and post in a block between triple backticks (```).

Comment: Sure, I will next time. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you forgot the set the [`label`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.artist.Artist.set_label.html#matplotlib.artist.Artist.set_label)*s* :

```
for column in file:
    if column != 'G/L ratio':
        plt.plot(file['G/L ratio'], file[column],
                 label=f"G/L ratio Vs. {column} [line]")    # <-- add this line
        plt.scatter(file['G/L ratio'], file[column],
                 label=f"G/L ratio Vs. {column} [scatter]") # <-- add this line

# ...

plt.legend(fontsize="small", ncol=3) # feel free to adjust/improve
```

Or maybe you added `plt.legend()` by error and in this case, just pull it back.

Note that you don't need a loop here, you can simply [`plot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html) the [`difference`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.difference.html) and add a marker :

```
(
    file.plot(
        x="G/L ratio",
        y=file.columns.difference(["G/L ratio"]),
        ax=plt.gca(), marker="o", figsize=(8, 4)
        # add the rest of arguments here
    )
);
```

Output (*1st*) :

[image]

Used input :

```
np.random.seed(2023)

file = pd.DataFrame({
    "G/L ratio": np.linspace(0, 1, 10)
    "A": np.random.rand(10),
    "B": np.random.rand(10),
    "C": np.random.rand(10),
})
```

Comment: thank you so much for your help. This solve my question! Cheers!

Comment: If the answer by @Timeless offers a solution to your Q, please consider [accepting the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) to close the post.